# Starling Feathers Extend Theme - Custom button

Tags: starling-framework

I am trying to work out how to use a sprite added to a themes sprite sheet as a button but not having much luck.

I have created the entire button with click state and label and added to the theme sprite sheet and need to use on a button. I have a number of custom buttons I would like to use but I would also like to use a number of the theme skin (Minimal skin).

I have looked at the extending themes section but unsure how to use a signal sprite image for 1 button, another for another button and the theme skin for others.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Look at the names property, this is how the theme "knows" what initializer function to call